Are these bodges equivalent to the traces they fix despite bypassing vias also connected to the traces?
Given these broken traces underneath two ICs:

For the broken traces that run pad-via-pad, is it OK to bodge on top of the pins of the ICs like this, even though this "bypasses" the vias?

I'm going to guess this should work, because the pads and via are all still electrically connected (one pad from each pair is still connected to the via), even if it's not in the same "order".

Before mounting the parts, use an ohmmeter to test out that the paths are complete and correct. Then do the same after the work is done.

Assuming this isn't running at very high speeds (MHz) then I don't see any problems. You might want to investigate why the traces burnt to a crisp however. A short between supply and ground would be one likely cause.

74HC is not very fast, 5-10ns rise time, and its output drivers are wimpy with an output impedance of around 50 ohms, which is useful as it provides "free" source termination without having to add resistors. This means it tends to not produce much noise, and not be picky about layout and decoupling. It also means if the board was designed with HC, it's probably using a rather low clock frequency (by modern standards) so a bit of wire isn't going to eat into the timing margins.
So there should be no issue with bodging.
For low noise emissions you should minimize the area between your bodge wire and the ground plane, as this minimizes inductance, impedance discontinuities, and the size of the loop antenna being formed. This means 1) using thin wire: wrapping wire is ideal for this, or thin enameled wire. And 2) route the wire over the board/ground plane as shown below, not over the chips, then stick it down with tape.

It's best to use transparent tape like kapton. This way, when someone sees the tape, they will also see the bodge wires and won't rip the tape to see what's under it, which would tear off the wires...

The remaining pad, and via, appear to be connected still.  So to rephrase more directly, the question is: is it okay to route Pin-Via-Pin or Pin-Pin-Via?
For the trace/wire lengths shown here, and 74HC edge rate, the added trace length has essentially no effect.  Risetime is several ns, and the bodgewire adds not even 1cm length (~30ps), I think?
The bigger effect is probably impedance: the height above ground plane is higher, and dielectric constant lower (mostly air, versus PCB substrate), raising Zo. The distance isn't very tall, so it's probably under 150Ω, versus the ~70Ω ballpark for traces; this can have the effect of doubling the length difference, like maybe it's effectively 2cm longer, but again -- it's so short already, it's unlikely to cause problems.
The via connects to something else, presumably, so there is still necessarily some stub length here (a tee geometry between transmission lines), and the original layout had about the same so clearly it's not too big of a deal (and, again, the distances are just so short in relation to the edge rate). The increase in total line length could still affect timing, but it seems unlikely that the design is so marginal that this would cause problems.

The fix going to the chip on the left is OK, because while pin 11 on the right is disconnected from the via, pin 3 on the left is still connected.  Similarly, the jumper connecting pins 4 and 8 on the right is fine because pin 4 is still connected to the via.
One more jumper is needed between pins between 2 and 6 (or 2 and 10) on the right to correct the break between pin 2 and the via.
I agree with bobflux and Tim Williams regarding the routing.
